# quartz job fail on Jboss hot deploy

Tags: java, jboss, hotdeploy

My web application used quartz 2.2.2 with Jboss 6.1. The data sources are configured in Jboss's standalone.xml. Each time the war is upgraded to a newer release, Jboss restarts but the quartz jobs fail to finish properly due to some persistance issue. Do you have any solution to the issue?

```
Cause : org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]ibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
The job [APPLICATION.StartDeliveryJob] execution is failed on APPLICATION [APPLICATION]. Cause : org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError]
The job [APPLICATION.StartDeliveryJob] is finished on APPLICATION [APPLICATION]
```